# Managing updates with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, create-table

I am aware that you can generate create scripts to generate database objects, but I am looking a way to generate an update script that compares two different schemas (two mapping files).

That way I can provide my users with easy database updating from any version to the current version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html). Have a look at the [Fluent-Migrator](http://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/) project.